# How to check when a record is replicated in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication

I have configured a database installed On-Premise to replicate certain tables on a Cloud SQL Server database hosted on Azure.

The replication task is scheduled to run at specific time everyday and I am looking for a way to check when a record was updated and what kind of operation was performed (Create, Update or Delete).

Is there any system table, stored procedure, or log that contains this information?

Answer (score 2):

yes,you can get the statements executed by distributor agent which are applied on subscriber by sp_browsereplcmds procedure. 
There is a nice article to get familiar with distributor databse system tables and other objects.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vinaythakur/2009/10/23/some-useful-commands-and-sp-for-transaction-replication/

all replication information stored in distribution database.Further it depends how you get.  Kindly go through the article and get the desired information.